# ipmitool set idrac mode

Tags: linux, command-line, remote-management

I have a DELL server R610, on this server there is a RHEL 6.4
This server has an idrac entreprise.

I would  like to configure the idrac from command line, avoiding reboot.

I read on the man page of ipmitool that I can use a command like :

```
#ipmitool lan set 1 mode dedicated
```

but the command return man page :

```
usage: lan set <channel> <command> <parameter>
```

I check another command from the man page, which is not existing on my server neither :

```
 #ipmitool lan get
```

Others commands are working without issue like :

```
 #ipmitool lan print
```

I am running ipmitool : ipmitool-1.8.11-13.el6.1.x86_64

I am wondering why I don't have all of the command available from man page ? 
Any idea ?

Comment: Does `ipmitool delloem lan get` work?

Comment: hello, here is the output of the command : #ipmitool delloem lan get
Shared LOM   :  shared with lom1
Failover LOM :  None

Comment: OK, try `ipmitool delloem lan set` to get a usage message. It looks like you ultimately want `ipmitool delloem lan set dedicated`

Comment: It works ! you can post this as an answer thank you. I didn't see the delloem option. Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up until a few years ago, `ipmitool` was undergoing rapid development. On some Linux distributions from around that time, the man page may not describe all the commands supported by the executable.

In your case, setting Dell DRAC and iDRAC parameters is supported by ipmitool 1.8.11, and is done using the `ipmitool delloem` command. So you could use these commands:

```
ipmitool delloem lan get
ipmitool delloem lan set dedicated
```